# Image not visible in Mixed Reality Capture

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I am rendering images on a canvas  in Unity on the Hololens 2. The images (different colors) are shown in Hololens remoting or when deploying the app as expected. If I try to record these images via Mixed Reality Capture, they are not shown though. I have a control 2D sprite next to these images, which is shown. I tried both single-pass instanced rendering, multi-pass rendering, Mobile-Particle-Additive shader and Sprites/Default shader, nothing changed the problem that the images appear normally in the app but are not shown in the Mixed Reality Capture.

What are possible reasons why objects are shown normally in the app but are not shown in the mixed reality capture?

Here is an example of the components that each of the image contains:
[image]
[image]

I changed the shader as described above and and the material to Default-Sprite material, this doesn't affect the Mixed Reality Capture. The InterfAnM element is also attached to a sprite I added to the scene, which shows up, so this should also not be the reason. The frame is a 2D sprite, it had a black background, I removed that with gimp and reimported again, also didn't change anything.

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: I am using this asset: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/2d/textures-materials/customizable-scifi-holo-interface-69794

It works well in the HL2, but not with Mixed Reality Capture. I will update the post to show screenshots of the inspector. Did not modify the code.

Comment: Also tried to uncheck "Cull transparent mesh", change material to Sprite-Default, both no effect.

Comment: Also tried to turn off the animator and the canvas group, also no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out some MRTK examples that contain a canvas with images, I found that this is a bug that also appears with other MRTK examples.
Bug described here: https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/10111